# NSMutableArry not getting added into NSuserdefaults

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I am try to add a `NSMutableArray` into the `NSUserDefault` **but it is always retuning null.**
I know that .so I'm even creating a mutable copy os array as well but still.

> Values returned from NSUserDefaults
>   are immutable, even if you set a
>   mutable object as the value. For
>   example, if you set a mutable string
>   as the value for "MyStringDefault",
>   the string you later retrieve using
>   stringForKey: will be immutable.

```
 NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray *myStoredEvents=[prefs objectForKey:@"MySavedEvents"];

NSMutableArray *myStoredEventsNew=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
myStoredEventsNew=myStoredEvents;
NSMutableArray *tempDic=[myevents objectAtIndex:eventId];//myevents a NSMutableArray

if(myStoredEventsNew != nil)
{
    [myStoredEventsNew insertObject:tempDic atIndex:0];
}
else
{
    [myStoredEventsNew insertObject:tempDic atIndex:myStoredEvents.count];
 }
NSLog(@"New dictonary before modification :%@",tempDic);
[prefs setObject:myStoredEventsNew forKey:@"MySavedEvents"];
[prefs synchronize];
```

Comment: `if(myStoredEventsNew == nil)
{
    [myStoredEventsNew insertObject:tempDic atIndex:0];` why to check for `nil` and then use it? Should it be `!=`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code --

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSLog(@"DEBUG :: %@",[prefs objectForKey:@"MySavedEvents"]);
    NSMutableArray *myStoredEvents;
    if ([prefs objectForKey:@"MySavedEvents"] == NULL) {
        myStoredEvents  =   [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }else{
        myStoredEvents=[[prefs objectForKey:@"MySavedEvents"] mutableCopy];
    }
    NSMutableArray *tempDic=[myevents objectAtIndex:eventId];//myevents a NSMutableArray

    [myStoredEvents addObject:tempDic];

    NSLog(@"New dictonary before modification :%@",myStoredEvents);
    [prefs setObject:myStoredEvents forKey:@"MySavedEvents"];
    [prefs synchronize];
```

May this solve your problem

Comment: thanks as i was taking  `mutableCopy` in a wrong way .

Answer (score 0):

you can save array in NSuserdefaults like this :-

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:yourArray forKey:@"MySavedEvents"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

and you can put check condition to check NSuserdefault like this :-

```
NSObject * object = [prefs objectForKey:@"MySavedEvents"];
if(object != nil){
   //object is there
}
```

You can put further conditions according to your need, this is just a basic structure of how to achieve this.